# How read a object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
Book[] titles;
titles = new Book[] {
new Book(5011,"Fishing Explained"),
new Book(1234, "Help is on the Way")
};
```

how can I read or access the value 5011 from a object array?

Comment: its really depends on your `Book` methods

Comment: We need to see the definition of the `Book` class. Typically, it will have a `.getBookId()` method or something similar.

Comment: The same way you access the value from a plain old `Book`. Think of it like this: `Book book = titles[n]; int x = book.whatever();` becomes `int x = titles[n].whatever();`.

Comment: it's sample code. assume it's Object[] item= new Object[] {5011, "Fishing Explained"}; @RafaEl

Comment: @akeel that doesn't help anything. we need to see your `Object` class/definition. see @Maroun's answer below

Comment: I'd use Hashmap!! 5011 as key and text as value

Answer (score 2):

`Book` must have this:

```
class Book {

    private int number;
    private String title;

    public Book(int number, String title) {
         this.number = number;
         this.title  = title;
    }

    //...
}
```

You should have a *getter* for that `int`:

```
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

You invoke it on the `Book` *object* like this:

```
int myNumber = titles[0].getNumber();
```

If you want to get the ID according to the title, you should consider using a `Map` or any other database that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class book you could access your book like that:

```
Book book = new Book("1","title");
```

Now you can get the values from the book like that:

```
book.getId();
```

this could be your book class:

```
public class Book {

    private String id = "";
    private String title = "";

    public Book(String id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Book class has two initial fields(used in Book class constructor) - I don't know the types of these fields - may be some id (int) and a title(String). You can add/use getter from Book class to read the value 5011/id. You can access the Book object from that array by titles [0].
So as a full answer:
titles[0].getId();

Answer (score 0):

You may provide basically setters/getters method in Book class. and then loop through titles and access using 
titles[your_index].geMethod(); hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the array is a `Book`. Accessing an individual element is just the usual array access syntax:

```
int numbers[] = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
int number = numbers[1]; // index 1, for example
```

And likewise, assuming your `Book` has some method named `getID()` (or whatever):

```
Book titles[] = new Book[] { ... };
Book title = titles[1];
int titleID = title.getID();
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
Book titles[] = new Book[] { ... };
int titleID = titles[1].getID();
```

Just remember that each element of the array is a `Book`, and array elements are accessed as `array[index]`. After that, you just use the exact same syntax you'd use with any other `Book`.